# PanGestureHandler jumpy animation when resetting value using Reanimated and Redash

Tags: react-native

I want to have the feeling of infinite/continuos pages where each page is a list of events of a different day.
When the component mounts, I load some data while showing a set of placeholder items. Next to the list on each side is a view of the same placeholder items so when the user scrolls sideways it appears to be the next day loading.
After some time I want to reset the transition of the and display the new data.

I'm using the `spring` function and `snapPoint` function from redash to handle the translation and stick to the borders of the phone.
I added a `cond` with the function `approximates` from redash so when the translation approximates to `-SCREEN_WIDTH` or `SCREEN_WIDTH` it uses the `call` function to call something from the JS side.

This is working properly, the problem comes when I want to reset the position of the list. I want to bring it back to the screen after a clock finishes, im trying with `set(this.translationX, 0)` but having not success.

Here an example: https://gph.is/g/ajmAXmB

On the constructor I have this:

```
this.isLoading = new Value(0);
this.translationX = new Value(0);
this.velocityX = new Value(0);
const state = new Value(State.UNDETERMITED);
this._onPanGestureEvent = onGestureEvent({
    translationX: this.translationX,
    state,
    velocityX: this.velocityX,
});
this.listTranslationX = spring(this.translationX, state, snapPoint(this.translationX, this.velocityX, snapPoints));
this.onScroll = onScroll({ y: this.props.scrollY });
```

This is the render function:

```
render() {
    return (
      <>
        <PanGestureHandler {...this._onPanGestureEvent} >
          <Animated.View style={[styles.wrapper, { transform: [{ translateX: this.listTranslationX }] }]} >
            <AnimatedFlatList
              scrollEventThrottle={16}
              style={{ flex: 1 }}
              renderItem={this.renderItem}
              data={this.props.items[0]}
              onScroll={this.onScroll}
            />
            {!this.props.isLoading || this.props.items.length === 0 ?
              <View style={styles.placeholderWrapper} >
                <SchedulePlaceholder />
              </View >
              : null}


          </Animated.View >
        </PanGestureHandler>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.placeholderLeft, { transform: [{ translateX: this.listTranslationX }] }]}>
            <SchedulePlaceholder />
        </Animated.View>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.placeholderRight, { transform: [{ translateX: this.listTranslationX }] }]}>
            <SchedulePlaceholder />
        </Animated.View>
        <Animated.Code exec={this.animatedCode} />
      </>
    );
  }
```

The animatedCode functions has:

```
animatedCode = () => {
  const clock = new Clock()
  const state = {
    finished: new Value(0),
    position: new Value(0),
    time: new Value(0),
    frameTime: new Value(0),
  }
  const config = {
    duration: new Value(1000),
    toValue: new Value(1),
    easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.linear),
  }
  return block([
    cond(and(approximates(this.listTranslationX, EXTREMITY), eq(this.isLoading, 0)),
      [set(this.isLoading, 1),
      call([new Value(-1)], this.onChangeDate),
      startClock(clock),
      timing(clock, state, config),
      cond(state.finished, [
        set(this.translationX, 0)
      ])]
    ),
    cond(and(approximates(this.listTranslationX, -EXTREMITY), eq(this.isLoading, 0)),
      [set(this.isLoading, 1),
      call([new Value(1)], this.onChangeDate),
      startClock(clock),
      timing(clock, state, config),
      cond(state.finished, [
        set(this.translationX, 0)
      ])]
    ),
  ]);
}
```

Ideally after some time (clock finishes) reset the position to show the list again. If there's a better way to show infinite sideways lists please share it here